# Is there any free web reporting program for php on linux?

Tags: php, linux, report

I need a free program like web reporting program on linux. I use crystal report on windows but I can't find for linux. I find many programs but non of them are free.

Comment: Did you google first to search on available tools on it. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Data Vision which is an open source reporting tool. Make a google search first. Try to spend little time for that.